# how to connect apache-drill with cassandra in embedded mode

Tags: cassandra-2.0, apache-drill

I want to connect drill with cassandra . One blog I found but when I follow instructions of that blog I got error . Any one know how to connect both ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Use Apache Drill with Cassandra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017755/how-to-use-apache-drill-with-cassandra)

Answer (score 0):

Drill (*till 1.4*) does not provide direct support for Cassandra. You can write your own patch over core drill to achieve this.

This [article](http://www.confusedcoders.com/bigdata/apache-drill/sql-on-cassandra-querying-cassandra-via-apache-drill) can be referred but it was tested for an older version of drill. It does not work for Drill **1.0+**

In future releases, we can expect direct support for cassandra from Drill People..:)